# Trying to make a Python program do a task at a certain time using datetime but it is not working, no errors output

Tags: python, datetime

I want to schedule a certain task from Python. I read the desired start time from a file and repeatedly compare this to the current time.  Here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import sys
current_time = datetime.now()
f = open("starttime.txt", "r")
start_time = f.read()
print(current_time)
print(start_time)

while True:
    if str(current_time) == str(start_time):
        print("the times match")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('not yet')
```

The `print`s work correctly, but when the start time arrives, the program keeps printing 'not yet'.  Is there any way to fix this?

Edit:  I tried the suggestions that Prune said in the answers section and I got an error when trying to convert a str obj into a datetime obj saying that the format is incorrect.  Here is the line of code:
`start_time = datetime.strptime("2018-9-12 20:00:00.000000", '%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S, %f')`

Edit 2:  My code is finally working!  Thanks Prune!

Comment: `current_time` is not changing within in the `while` loop - it is fixed to the time it was when you set it.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You failed to update the `current_time` within your loop: it's still stuck at the time you began the program.
2. You're checking for an exact match.  Since `now` returns the time in microseconds, it's unlikely that you'll hit the exact time in looping.  Instead, I suggest that you use an inequality.

For instance:

```
if datetime.now() >= start_time:
```

... where you've already converted `start_time` to a `datetime` object.

---

Make that *three* problems.  You also haven't properly formatted your `datetime` conversion for the string you feed it: you have punctuation in your string that is not represented in your conversion format.  Try this:

```
>>> datetime.strptime("2018-09-12 20:10:13.141593",
                      '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Result:

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 12, 20, 10, 13, 141593)
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!  I just have one question, when trying to convert start_time into a datetime object, I get an error that the format does not match what the text is, even though I put it in the right format.  This is the line of code that I used: `start_time = datetime.strptime(thing, '%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S, %f')`    By the way, thing is the new variable for the string version of start_time.

Comment: We can't help you without the applicable code to reproduce the problem.  Please edit that into your posting.  Don't read from the file; just assign the literal string to `thing` (which is a very unhelpful variable name).

Comment: Sorry about that, when using the string itself, I still get the same error.  Here is the updated code: `start_time = datetime.strptime("2018-9-12 20:00:00.000000", '%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S, %f')`

Comment: I finally got my code to work with your help.  Thank you for your patience as now looking back I seemed to have made a lot of careless mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are taking as input will contain EOL(end of line) characters at the end of the file. First try to delete those characters (\n \r etc).